# How to set paragraph spacing between Text nodes in TextFlow?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm using a TextFlow container to layout Text elements on a UI.  I cannot figure out how to set the vertical spacing *between* Text nodes - ala paragraph spacing in a web browser.  I am dynamically adding the text like so:

```
for(String strParagraph : data)
{
   Text line = new Text(strParagraph + "\n");
   txtArea.getChildren().add(line);
}
```

I have tried setting the TextFlow's lineSpacing property, but this sets the spacing between *all* lines, including wrapped text.  I've also tried setting the `-fx-padding` and `-fx-margin` styles on the Text node, with no effect.

Comment: Wouldn’t adding two newlines (`"\n\n"`) be sufficient?

Comment: Two newlines adds exactly one full line-height of spacing.  I want a variable amount of spacing that can be controlled by CSS.

Comment: Is using an actual WebView an option?